# Websocket некорректное отключение клиента, Как проверить что клиент прервал связь?

Tags: php, websocket

Подскажите пожалуйста, как произвести проверку на отключение клиента от `WebSocket` сервера. Есть вот такой код:

```
function startWebsocketServer() 
{    
    $socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://0.0.0.0:8080", $errno, $errstr);
    if (!$socket) 
    {
        die("$errstr ($errno)\n");
    }

    $connects = array();
    while (true) 
    {
        //формируем массив прослушиваемых сокетов:
        $read = $connects;
        $read []= $socket;
        $write = $except = null;

        if (!stream_select($read, $write, $except, null)) 
        {//ожидаем сокеты доступные для чтения (без таймаута)
            break;  
        }

        if (in_array($socket, $read)) 
        {
            //есть новое соединение
            //принимаем новое соединение и производим рукопожатие:
            if (($connect = stream_socket_accept($socket, -1)) && $info = handshake($connect)) 
            {                       
                $connects[] = $connect;//добавляем его в список необходимых для обработки
                onOpen($connect, $info);//вызываем пользовательский сценарий      
            }
            unset($read[ array_search($socket, $read) ]);
        }

        foreach($read as $connect) 
        {//обрабатываем все соединения
            $data = fread($connect, 100000);

            if (!$data) 
            { //соединение было закрыто
                fclose($connect);
                unset($connects[ array_search($connect, $connects) ]);
                onClose($connect);//вызываем пользовательский сценарий
                continue;
            }

           /*
            * onMessage($connects, $data) для отправки каждому пользователю своего сообщения
            * заменить $connects на $connect и убрать цикл в функции onMessage
            */

           onMessage($connects, $data);//вызываем пользовательский сценарий, для отправки одном
        }       
    }
    fclose($socket);   
}
```

Он рабочий, но есть одна проблема, если клиент отключается некорректно - т.е. например прервалось соединение с интернетом, то скрипт через некоторый промежуток времени начинает жутко тормозить, до того момента пока тот же самый клиент вновь не наладит связь с сервером! Как сюда внедрить проверку на то, что клиент отключился и удалить не работающий ресурс из массива $connects ? Если закрыть вкладку браузера, то отключение клиента проходит корректно и проблема отсутствует!

Comment: heartbeat/handshake ?

Comment: Пользуйтесь  stream_set_timeout function http://am1.php.net/manual/ru/function.stream-set-timeout.php

Comment: Вам необходимо установить тайм-аут сокета, в этом случае вы получите сообщение об ошибке, если клиент не ответит своевременно.Также проверьте socket_set_option http://php.net/manual/ru/function.socket-set-option.php

Comment: И, наконец, ознакомьтесь с этой замечательной статьей о том, как эффективно использовать сокеты в PHP: «Программирование сокетов PHP, сделано правильно https://www.christophh.net/2012/07/24/php-socket-programming/

Comment: Или воспользуйтесь этим ответом http://stackoverflow.com/a/4012657/6120970

Comment: Vanya Avchyan - Ни одно из Ваших предложений не сработало stream_set_timeout($connect, 2); не устанавливается, это видно если распечатать $info = stream_get_meta_data($connect); в $info['timed_out'] все время пусто, даже если я вдруг чего то пропустил, то и if ($info['timed_out']) 
                {
                    echo 'Истекло время соединения!';} тоже не работает! Что делать, может я чего то не понимаю?